# How to do an application without form in C#?

Tags: c#, windowless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing a Windows system tray application with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995195/writing-a-windows-system-tray-application-with-net)

Hi,
I am programming an application in .NET and I don't want to put it a windows interface.
I remember some time ago I did it with inheriting from the ApplicationContext class but now I can't achieve it.

How I could do it?

Thanks!

**Edit:** 
It's an application that is managed by a notify icon. It must appear the icon near the system clock but not a form. I'm doing this:

```
class Sync : ApplicationContext
{
    public Sync()
    {
        ...
    }
}

[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Sync());
}
```

Comment: What type of application are you developing? Console window, Windows Service, Library?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995195/writing-a-windows-system-tray-application-with-net

Answer (score 25):

(obsolete now that you've edited the question to state systray; left for reference only)

If you want an exe without any UI (not even a console), but without it being a service etc - then write a windows forms app, but just don't show any forms! The fact that it is a winform app simply means you don't get a console window - but no UI is shown except that which you write. Look at the `Main` method (usually in `Program.cs` in the VS templates) to see what I mean.

Comment: So easy. Just delete the form and replace the `Main()`-code. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 9):

You can write a Console Application or a Service or something of that sort. What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

How about using a [console application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164014.aspx) or a [Windows Service](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/2173801)?

Answer (score 1):

see here: http://bluehouse.wordpress.com/2006/01/24/how-to-create-a-notify-icon-in-c-without-a-form/

Edit: added the code in the link to this answer in case the link dies. Credit goes to the author for this code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;

class ControlContainer : IContainer
{
    ComponentCollection _components;

    public ControlContainer()
    {
        _components = new ComponentCollection(new IComponent[] { });
    }

    public void Add(IComponent component) { }
    public void Add(IComponent component, string Name) { }
    public void Remove(IComponent component) { }

    public ComponentCollection Components
    {
        get { return _components; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _components = null;
    }
}

class MainEntryClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
        Application.Run();
    }
}

class SomeClass
{
    ControlContainer container = new ControlContainer();
    private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon1;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        this.notifyIcon1 = new NotifyIcon(container);
    }
}
```