# Show application icons in notification area in windows application C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, winforms

I created a windows services in c# application. For install that application I created the installer. Installer running fine. Installer installing services successfully and starting services also.

[image]

I want show services icon in notification area and when click on that icons on notification area , application should be open.

**Just like skypeicon showing in the image.**

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and setup project is done in InstalledShield.

Comment: You mean windows service or winform application ? A windows service doesn't have a winform to show by clicking on icon . Windows services can be viewed by running " services.msc " command on run .

Comment: Running window services like skype run their services. I want show similar icons in notification area and when click on that icon application should be open.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display a system tray icon for C# window service.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652254/how-can-i-display-a-system-tray-icon-for-c-sharp-window-service)