# Systray application with Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, systray

I have a small service with c# (.net 4) that mainly detects session changes such as computer locks and unlocks and reports to a backend sql 2014 express server.

I want to add a system tray application that will interact with the service / backend to capture more data and do some interactions with the logged on user.

Can anyone point me in the direction as far as a tutorial or overview of Application / Service creation and communication?  Is this a WCF thing?  Should the application and service be in the same project?

Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a system tray icon for C# window service.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652254/how-can-i-display-a-system-tray-icon-for-c-sharp-window-service)

Answer (score 2):

You can have both projects in the same solution. There are many options to interact with your service. The best choice depends on the actions you want the UI application to perform with the service.

My choice would be to use a WCF service hosted within your windows service application. There are many examples out there for self-hosted WCF services (one is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/650869/Creating-a-Self-Hosted-WCF-Service), though I didn't read it all).

Please note #1: To add the service reference to the client, you need to start the host outside Visual Studio in case you have both projects in the same solution, as the "Add service reference" menu item will not be available when running something in Visual Studio.

Please note #2: It might be a good idea to create your windows service to be able to run as a GUI application when `Environment.UserInteractive == true`. To do so, I tend to modify the `Main` method to either start the service, or to start a GUI using the code found when creating a Windows Forms application (`Application.Run(new SomeForm())`, etc.). That makes debugging a *lot* easier.

---

To avoid confusion: I'm **not** talking about creating a user-interactive service! I'm talking about making your service application so that it can run both as a service and as an application for debugging purposes. Like this, for example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (Environment.UserInteractive)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new DebugForm(new MyService()));
    }
    else
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new MyService() };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

Add new methods `DoStart()` and `DoStop()` to your service class that just call `OnStart` and `OnStop` to simulate the service being started. Call `DoStart` from the form's `OnLoad` handler and `DoStop` from the form's `OnClose` handler.

Of course you need to add `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Drawing` references to your project to allow forms to be used.

That way you can just run your service application from Visual Studio without the "A service can not be run as an application" message.

**You still need to create a UI application to interact with the service! The above only helps for debugging the service and is something I've come to love, because it makes development much easier!**

Comment: Hi Thorsten, thanks for the info.  The reason I wanted the application part is because from everything I've read, services that are userinteractive is a big no no as well as no longer supported starting with Windows Vista / 7.

Comment: Hi Thorsten, thanks for the info.  The reason I wanted the application part is because from everything I've read, services that are userinteractive is a big no no as well as no longer supported starting with Windows Vista / 7.

Comment: Oh! User interactive services *are not possible* anymore. You're misunderstanding me! I mean: Modify your service program.cs so that it runs as a service if `Environment.UserInteractive == false` and starts a normal application **just for debugging purposes** if `Environment.UserInteactive == true`! That has nothing to do with the service running user interactive!

Answer (score 1):

If you only need basic interaction to a service (start/stop/restart/status...), [ServiceController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx) will give you enough utilities.

Anything more than that would require a more elaborate approach, typically using [IPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx), writing to the same database and/or calling back to a web application...

There is no need to have service and the windows client to be in the same project. However, it would be nice that you can **define your service name at one place**, since your system tray app would need the service name to interact with your service.

Putting those 2 projects together or not is your call, but remember the relationship between your application and your service. Can your application stand alone without the service? It would not be nice if someone update the service without realizing that they also need to update another application in another project.