# What type of C# application is needed for a background application that needs a system tray icon?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, system-tray, background-application, project-setup

I've been tasked to write a C# application that, in "normal" mode, is basically windowless, left running in the background.  Accessibility to the application would be through an icon in the system tray.  I thought that a **Windows Service** C# project would be the way to go about this, but after reading the answers to [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652254/how-can-i-display-a-system-tray-icon-for-c-sharp-window-service), I'm wondering if a Windows service application is really what I need here.  Can what I need be achieved with a **Windows Form Application**, or did Microsoft intend one of the other project types, such as the **Console Application** or **Empty Project**, for this type of application?

Comment: Multiple possibilities. WinForms is an option.

Comment: NotifyIcon is a Winforms class.  Pretty big hint.

Comment: The best approach depends on what the requirements are for your application. Does it need to be able to run unattended, without a desktop (I.e. start even if a user has not logged in to the machine)? If so, part of the solution pretty much has to be a windows service. If the app only needs to function when a user has logged in then a winforms app, or wpf app, would be two options.

Comment: it depends a lot on what it needs to do, a service with a windows form front end to show what the service is up to maybe the better option

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! :D