# Aero border and other controls in a TrayIcon menu

Tags: c#, wpf, aero, system-tray, trayicon

I'm writing a system tray app for Windows (with much info gleaned from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995195)). I have the ContextMenu working - you can right click and execute functions that way.

I want to have a modern, rich interface pop up on a left click, however, much like most of the built in Windows 7 (and possibly Vista) tray icons have. By this I refer to the Aero lining, and apparent ability to add seemingly arbitrary controls (e.g. volume slider, network chooser).

I'm not really sure where to start. Is it a matter of creating a "normal" window and restricting it heavily? If so, how? (If it comes down to Windows Forms vs. WPF, the latter is preferable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, you can display anything you like when you receive the mouse click on your notification icon.  Usually it's a pop-up menu, but you could show a window instead.

Comment: It seems increasingly likely to me that it is a matter of making a small customised window, I'll see if there're any more suggestions before marking this as the answer though. Cheers.

Comment: UISpy can show some information about various popups.  I just tried it on the volume slider window.  I normally use Spy++, but it doesn't have UISpy's focus-tracking.

Comment: UISpy sounds really useful, cheers. I don't know if I'm missing something obvious but I have the Windows SDK v7.1 installed, and it doesn't seem to be in there. Everywhere says it's in the Windows SDK though. Any idea?

Comment: Mine is in my v7.0 directory (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin).  Off the top of my head, I have no idea how I have both v7.0 and v7.1 installed.

Comment: Just installed v7.0 alongside 7.1 and sure enough, there it is. Wonder why on earth they removed it, seems useful.