# How can I create an application in WPF that runs in background

Tags: c#, wpf

My aim is to place my application in the tray bar but I don't know how to do that for a WPF application ! (for a winform there is lots of docs but I don't find anything for Wpf)

Thanks

Comment: Does the app *only* exist in the tray, or is there a foreground component as well?

Comment: Also, look at this link, it may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995195/writing-a-windows-system-tray-application-with-net

Comment: no it's a normal application but i'd like to reduce it

Comment: I found that finally : http://possemeeg.wordpress.com/2007/09/06/minimize-to-tray-icon-in-wpf/ I'm testing if it's work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing it, I recommand http://possemeeg.wordpress.com/2007/09/06/minimize-to-tray-icon-in-wpf/

But be sure your icon is an an “Embedded Ressource” not “Ressource” in properties in Visual Studio.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If this is your answer, you probably want to click the check-mark to the left to mark it as complete :)

Comment: Thanks :) (I have to wait still 7 hours to validate my own answer ^^)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [this library](http://www.hardcodet.net/projects/wpf-notifyicon) for the tray icon, and to not have any windows you should remove any [`StartupUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startupuri.aspx) that may be defined in the App class by default. Then you can override [`OnStartup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onstartup.aspx) to prepare any logic that your application should perform.

Not sure if you can assign a `TaskbarIcon` of this library directly to the application since it is normally used on Windows. But you can create a dummy popup to make it show up.

```
public TaskbarIcon MyTaskbarIcon { get; set; }

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    Popup pu = new Popup();
    pu.Child = MyTaskbarIcon;
    //...
}
```

If you can have windows you can create a TaskbarIcon there and then you can call [`Hide()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.hide.aspx) if you need it to completely disappear.