# c# run application without a dos/form window

Tags: c#

Anyone knows a way to run a c# application without a window popping up(either form or dos window) or having it at the task bar as an application . I want it to be seen at processes tab at task manager or at the system icons(at the right of the task bar).

Comment: You may want to create system tray application. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995195/writing-a-windows-system-tray-application-with-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

then you need to create a Windows Service.

Visual Studio => New Project => Windows => Windows Service

Here is some more information:

- [Introduction to Windows Service Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [How to: Create Windows Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In windows app setting you can for a form set

```
ShowinTaskbar = false;
```