# How to get mouse position using .NET

Tags: windows, windows-services, position, mouse

Im developing a WINDOWS SERVICE that is just suposed to log the mouse position every 10 sec. The problem is that i cant get the mouse position... i call user32 for the method "GetCursorPos(ref Point)" but i always get |0,0|

can anyone tell me how to properly get the position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is probably to write a [system tray application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995195/writing-a-windows-system-tray-application-with-net).

You can do this in a windows service if you make that service interactive, but there are a number of security issues if you go down that route.

For full details refer to

http://www.freelists.org/post/program-l/C-creating-a-service-that-logs-mouse-and-keyboard-input,1