# Is there a base class or SDKs for system tray based app on Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm writing a System Tray based app with C# and I wonder if there's a pre-existing class I can reuse.
Basically, the behavior is very similar to the standard Windows volume control and calendar widgets:

- When the notify icon is clicked, a form/dialog is popped up. If the "show hidden icons" button was clicked to access the notify icon, it'll be closed.
- The form/dialog is aligned to bottom right of the same screen as the notify icon, whichever screen it is on.
- When the focus is lost, the form will close.

I could try to implement all these behaviours. But if there's a standard windows control, I'd like to reuse it to get the same look and feel. Thanks.

Comment: In WinForms, you already have the NotifyIcon component for that (which uses [Shell_NotifyIconW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyiconw)). You can present anything you want when the status icon notifies an *interaction*. The rest is up to you (and you can implement ~whatever you please) -- `Screen.FromHandle()` gives you the current Screen and its WorkingArea. The `Activate`  / `Deactivate` events...

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [NotifyIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

You're then going to want to hook OnClick events and there you can use conditions to determine if it was a left click -> do something.

Example:

```
void onclick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

There's some useful tips and information in this thread aswell: [How can I make a .NET Windows Forms application that only runs in the System Tray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995195/how-can-i-make-a-net-windows-forms-application-that-only-runs-in-the-system-tra?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'm aware of NotifyIcon. As for the form itself, I wonder if there's anything in Windows SDK to make it look and feel like the standard forms, such as the calendar or volume control popups?
I could style the form myself, but I just thought I should reuse if there's existing APIs. Thanks.

Comment: Ah I see, I interpreted your post as that you wanted a built-in class for a tray app. (might want to rephrase your question to focus more on the app-style part)